# Create table using inner join on pre-existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can join two tables, but i am trying to save them as a new table but it keeps saying my select syntax is wrong?

I am extremely new to SQL server

```
Create table New_table AS
SELECT * 
from Old_Table inner join id on Old_table.id=Other_table.id
```

Comment: That syntax `create table ... as` would work on most RDBMS. In fact it's the SQL standard way of creating a table from a query. However, SQL Server uses `INTO` instead, MarcinJ's  answer is correct. Just explicitly state all the columns in your query, as there could be columns that have the same names on participating tables

Answer (score 1):

You need [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT Old_table.id
     , Old_table.foo
     , Other_Table.bar
     , Other_Table.foo AS baz -- foo has to be renamed, can't have two columns with the same name
  INTO New_table 
  FROM Old_Table 
 INNER 
  JOIN Other_Table 
    ON Old_table.id = Other_table.id
```

Comment: Create table New_table AS
SELECT * INTO New_table
from Old_table
INNER
JOIN Other_table
on Old_table.ID = Other_table.ID this doesnt work either, how do i format it like you have done

Comment: It works fine until I add the CREATE TABLE New_table AS part

Comment: @MrGlen  You don't want to add the CREATE TABLE, just do what MarcinJ has shown.

Comment: When I do that it says, Column name 'id' in New_table is specified more than once

Comment: Right, you will need to specify all columns from `Old_table` and `New_table`, excluding (or renaming via `AS`) the columns that are the same in both columns, like `id`. `*` won't work here because `id` exists in both and you can't have two columns named the same in a table.